# CFQUERYPARAM breaking with "+" in URL

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, cfqueryparam

I have a query:

```
  SELECT id FROM table WHERE field1=<cfqueryparam value="#URL.field1#" 
    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
  AND field2=<cfqueryparam value="#URL.field2#" 
    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">
  AND field3=<cfqueryparam value="#URL.field3#" 
    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar">;
```

Id is an INTEGER in MySQL, but the above query returns an Id that has not come from the table, and is not even an INTEGER, it seems to be a random BIGINT!
If I remove the CFQUERYPARAM it works though...

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE field1='#URL.field1#' 
        AND field2='#URL.field2#'
        AND field3='#URL.field3#';
```

Field1, Field2 and Field3 are all VARCHARS in the Database, but in the URL they contain "+", eg 
`Field1=text+moretext`

If I remove the "+" from the URL strings, it works fine! I'm aware the "+" is a representation of a space, if I actually type a whitespace into the URL again it works fine. It's only breaking when there is a "+" present.

What have I done wrong? Or what do I do to make CFQUERYPARAM work with "+" from the URL

Answer (score 1):

The `Field=text+moretext` in the url will come through to Url.Field1 as `text moretext`, because spaces in URLs can be encoded as pluses.

If you want an actual `+` sign in the final variable, use `%2B`, or apply the `UrlEncodedFormat` to the original link.

If this all works, then I guess the odd behaviour with the random ID may be related to the default database value when the where clause fails to match - try `SELECT id FROM table WHERE 1=0` and see if you get the random ids?

Comment: Does that explain why the queries return different results with and without cfqueryparam, though?

Comment: Peter, why did you edit the cfqueryparam tags out of his question?

Comment: Running the query "SELECT id FROM table WHERE 1=0" just returns 0 rows. As I stated the only problem is when CFQUERYPARAM tags are used. 

What was your edit Peter? As all it seemed to do was hide the CFQUERYPARAM tags in the question

Comment: Sorry, I'm don't know what happened to those cfqueryparam tags... it wasn't deliberate! Must have been a SO or browser bug. The edit I was referring to was to my answer - the last paragraph. StackOverflow has a design feature where edits within a certain period don't leave an audit trail, so there is no indication that I added the final paragraph afterwards.

Comment: As for the problem itself... it does seem odd. Comcar, can you update the question with the MySQL table definition (i.e. `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>`), and confirm what CF Admin Datasource settings you are using?

Comment: Dammit I forgot to mention this in the first place... this is why I was querying about the "+" in the URL, if I remove it, it works.